# Super Slow Loading and Scrolling of Contacts in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am creating a list where I could invite users, so loading all the persons from the phone book.
Now, If I compare the invite speed of Whatsapp with my app, then my app is miserable.

Here I have two issues

1. My progress indicator freezes for 3-4 seconds during the contacts list fetching..
2. My Scroll bar is choppy/lagging/freezing.

Kindly help with the best practices when working with listview builder.

```
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    contacts = ContactsController.getContacts();
  }
```

Here is my build function

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _buildContactsCardList(context);
}


_buildContactsCardList(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<List<Contact>>(
      future: contacts,
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return const Center(
            child: Text("Error Fetching Contacts",
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  fontSize: 16,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                )),
          );
        }
        if (snapshot.data == null) {
          return const Center(
            child: SizedBox(height: 50, child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
          );
        }

        if (snapshot.data.length == 0) {
          return const Center(
            child: SizedBox(height: 50, child: Text("No Contacts Found")),
          );
        }
        return ListView.separated(
            primary: false,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
            separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Divider(
                color: Colors.grey.shade300,
                thickness: 1,
              );
            },
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              Contact contact = snapshot.data![index];
              return ListViewItem(
                  user: OnboardingUser.fromContacts(contact),
                  isContact: true,
                  isFriend: false);
            });
      },
    );
  }
```

Here is the line item for each user fetched

```
Widget ListViewItem(
      {required OnboardingUser user,
      required bool isContact,
      required bool isFriend}) {
    String tempName = "${user.firstName ?? ''} ${user.lastName ?? ""}";
    user.firstName =
        tempName.length > 15 ? tempName.substring(0, 15) + "..." : tempName;

    return Row(
      children: [
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            CircleAvatar(
              radius: 25,
              backgroundImage: NetworkImage(''),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        const SizedBox(width: 10),
        Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Text(
              "${user.firstName ?? ''} ${user.lastName ?? ""}",
              style: const TextStyle(
                fontSize: 16,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
            isContact
                ? Text(user.phoneNumber ?? '')
                : Text(
                    'Class ${user.grade}',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 14,
                      color: Colors.grey,
                    ),
                  ),
          ],
        ),
        const Spacer(),
        isContact
            ? InviteButton(user, isContact, isFriend)
            : AddFriendButton(user, isContact, isFriend),
      ],
    );
  }
```